# How to change the text of “permission denied” in Linux?

Tags: linux, root

All of us when we are a user in Linux (Not root), try to do some things that require root permission.
For example you change directory to  `/root` and you'll get an error that said "permission denied" :(
My question is, how to change this text ? Maybe i want it say "Try it as root".

Answer (score 3):

These messages come from the C standard library, namely [strerror](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). Where they are depends on the C library your distribution uses, and possibly also on the distribution.

On Debian, with glibc, they are under `/usr/share/locale` in the `libc.mo` files, as part of the `libc-l10n` package.

To change them, you will need to build your own custom version of the C library, install it, and keep it up to date.

This is going to be a lot of work, have fun.

Also, the English messages are standardized by POSIX. This means everyone who knows Unix will expect "Permission denied" and will get utterly confused when reading "Try as root" instead. In particular because in many cases you might actually want to put proper permissions into place, and not "try as root".

Comment: `$ strings "$(locate libc.mo | head -n 1 )" | grep -i perm` -> nothing (Ubunrtu 20.04.3)

Comment: @Hannu `$ strings /usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo | grep Perm
Permission denied` (did you actually **look** at the strings output? ...).

Comment: Yes Actually, my libc.mo does NOT contain "perm".  ( strings /usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo )

Comment: as `$ file $(which bash)` says `dynamically linked` I'd guess it is in one of the dynamically linked items, as `cd` is a shell builtin and `strings $(which bash) | grep perm` prints just one `permitted`.

Comment: `$ cd /root/` -> `bash: cd: /root/: Permission denied`, `$ type -a cd` -> `cd is a shell builtin`

Comment: @Hannu I am sure you'll figure out where it is on your system. On **my** system, which is **not** Ubuntu, it's in `libc.mo`. Along with all the other messages. And surprisingly, shell builtins use libc, too ...

Comment: Well, tell which system that is then, the above might be specific to it, and similar ones. Oh, I see now that you have done something in line with that.

Comment: @Hannu Did you actually **read** my answer? Because it's in the answer ... EOT.

Comment: =) i did now.... But as Ubuntu is Debian based, the relation apparently isn't a guarantee that it will be "the same"